# Antenna impedance matching within metallic enclosures

Tags: rf, surface-mount, impedance-matching

What im trying to achieve is kind of an chip antenna breakout board, since it must sit within a metallic groove.

The plan is a PCB of 10mm diameter with an U.Fl connector on the back and an antenna and a pi matching network on the front.

[image]

I also tried to calculate the required trace width with 0.4mm, 1.0mm and 1.6mm PCBs, but first iterations of this design showed a big difference between calculation and measurement with a VNA within the metallic enclosure.

So I'd like to know what best practice would be to choose a matching network or what parts of the design I could change to make this design more viable.

Comment: It sounds like it's your antenna and not the matching components that might be the problem when inside a metal box.

Comment: If the metal box is within the near field of the antenna, it will "detune" it and it will no longer match the expected impedance.  Here is a link that talks about near fields. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Near_and_far_field#Electromagnetically_short_antennas

Comment: What‘s the frequency? As you obviously did not calculate the metallic groove it is no wonder that your calculations anf the measurements dont match. Your metallic groove seems to be in the near field of the chip antenna, so it is actually a part of the antenna.

Comment: The frequency is 2.4Ghz. Yeah i didnt calculate the groove just because it is out of scope of my knowledge. So its still trial and error without a full simulation of the enclosure/grooves?